# unity touch button only with this tag

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine, touch

So I have a touch script in unity for a simple touch on a 2d sprite with a box collider:

```
    var platform : RuntimePlatform = Application.platform;

 function Update(){
     if(platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer){
         if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
             if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began){
                 checkTouch(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
             }
         }
     }else if(platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXEditor){
         if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             checkTouch(Input.mousePosition);
         }
     }
 }

 function checkTouch(pos){
     var wp : Vector3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
     var touchPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
     var hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos);

     if (hit){
         Debug.Log("touched");
     }
 }
```

But I want that when the object that is clicked/touched has a certain tag the Debug.Log will be different

Comment: Have you tried `Debug.Log(hit.tag)` ?

Comment: No because the debug.log is just a tester, if I get that to work the I am planning to put in some other actions

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying your clicking doesn't work on objects?

Comment: No I'm saying that at this point when you click on an object it will run the "Debug.Log("touched")". This will not be a part of my game in the future it is just a way to test if the script is working, so I'm not looking for a way to only run the Debug.log with a click on a game object with a specific tag, I'm looking for a way to run "a not known yet action" with a click on a game object with a specific tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `System.Action`.

```
public System.Action _action;
...

public void FutureAction()
{
    //Whatever you want this function to perform
}
...

//When you know the action that you want it to perform
_action = FutureAction;
...

//When you want to call this action, in your checkTouched function for example
if (hit.CompareTag("myTag"))
    _action(); //This will call whatever action was saved into the variable.
```

I hope that helps!

EDIT:
I wrote my code in C#, but the equivalent in javascript would work similarly.

Comment: Thank you very much you whent the right way, my wishes were only achievable much more easier: I Just replaced the "if (hit){" with "if(hit.CompareTag("tag")){"